# How to wrap text in multiple <span> containers without a line break?

Tags: html, css

How can I implement wrapping for the text in multiple  containers?

I need the text to wrap smoothly, but instead, if the text in one span is too long it moves to the next line instead of wrapping. How can I make it wrap instead of inserting line breaks?

```css
span {
  margin: 2px;
  border: 1px dotted #cccccc;
  padding: 4px 10px 4px 10px; 
    line-height: 1.8;
    word-wrap; normal;
    display: inline-block;
    
    }
div {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  width: 400px;
  word-wrap: break-word;

}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>lalala</span>
  <span>lalala lalala lalala lalala lalala lalala lalala lalala lalala lalala lalala lalala</span>
  <span>lalala lalala</span>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tzje3bgq/1/

Comment: remove inline-block?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this? Is this what you want to accomplish?

EDIT: Updated the answer based on @Temani Afif comment

```css
span {
  margin: 2px;
  border: 1px dotted #cccccc;
  padding: 4px 10px 4px 10px; 
  line-height: 1.8;
  word-wrap; normal;
}
div {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  width: 400px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>lalala</span>
  <span>lalala lalala lalala lalala lalala lalala lalala lalala lalala lalala lalala lalala</span>
  <span>lalala lalala</span>
</div>
```